# Automatically Increment Number by Group and Entry

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently trying to create a number that increases per entry and group in my table via a form.
The form is rather simple it utilizes a `ComboBox` to select the group from a different table. The generated number should start at 1 and increase for every new entry separately for each selected group.

**Code:**

My code attempts to create the number `BeforeUpdate` by searching for the `DMax()` of the variable for the group selected via `ComboBox`. Unfortunately, in this current state, the code does not increment the variable called `Nummer` but it does not throw an Error either.

```
Private Sub Nummer_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Nummer = Nz(DMax("[Nummer]", "Bau-Tagesbericht", "[Baustelle] = Kombinationsfeld354.Value")) + 1

End Sub
```

Variables:

Group: `Baustelle`

Variable that should be incremented: `Nummer`

Name of the `Comobox`: `Kombinationsfeld354`

**I appreciate any kind of help, thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable - and set 0 (zero) for *Null*:

```
Nummer = Nz(DMax("[Nummer]", "Bau-Tagesbericht", "[Baustelle] = " & Kombinationsfeld354.Value & ""), 0) + 1
```

If text value, use single quotes:

```
Nummer = Nz(DMax("[Nummer]", "Bau-Tagesbericht", "[Baustelle] = '" & Kombinationsfeld354.Value & "'"), 0) + 1
```

Comment: Then you are left with good old debugging. What does `Kombinationsfeld354.Value` hold? Will `DMax("[Nummer]", "[Bau-Tagesbericht]", "[Baustelle] = SomeKnownValue")` return a value, etc.

Comment: Interestingly it now displays the error 3075 which apparently refers to a syntax mistake. Is the value returned by `kombinationsfeld` allowed to be a string?